# How to plot the function the absolute value of x*(x-1)^(1/3) using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to plot `f(x)=abs(x*(x-1)^(1/3))` on `[0,2]`:

[image: abs(x*(x-1)^(1/3))]

I have to use `tikzpicture` environment but I am not able to do it in a nice way.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x>=0&&\x<=1,abs(\x*(\x-1)^(1/3)),\x*(\x-1)^(1/3));}]
    \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            legend style={cells={align=left}},
            legend cell align={left},
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=81,domain=0:2,name path=f] {f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: What I get]

The same effect is produced if I try with `\addplot[very thick,red,samples=81,domain=0:2,name path=f] {abs(x*(x-1)^(1/3))};`:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            legend style={cells={align=left}},
            legend cell align={left},
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=81,domain=0:2,name path=f] {abs(x*(x-1)^(1/3))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: If I do not use declare function the result is the same]

Thanks and have a nice 2`0`19!

Comment: Your document is incomplete

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You set the brackets in such a way that the compiler sees `(x-1)^(1/3)`. It does not know how to plot the third root of a negative number, and let's it be. I fixed the brackets to obtain

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x>=0&&\x<=1,\x*abs(\x-1)^(1/3),\x*(\x-1)^(1/3));}]
    \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            legend style={cells={align=left}},
            legend cell align={left},
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=161,domain=0:2,name path=f] {f(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis on top,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis lines = center,
            xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            legend style={cells={align=left}},
            legend cell align={left},
        ]
        \addplot[very thick,red,samples=161,domain=0:2,name path=f] {abs(x)*abs(x-1)^(1/3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Happy New Year!

Comment: Good to know! This time I did not forget the odd samples haha, Happy New Year!!

Comment: @manooooh Oh, this was a real question (and not just a trick to have the first question in 2019)? ;-)

Comment: It is? You know I thought about it while taking a shower but for the time zones I said "There is no way it is the first question of 2019" `:D`. If so, you are the first best answer of 2019 `;)`.